# URL Parameters and AJAX Problem

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, servlets, parameters

I have a JSP page that when loaded calls a JavaScript function (loadData()), this function uses an AJAX request to retrieve data from a servlet and return the necessary HTML content to the page.

I want to call this url from a button and pass a URL Parameter (....jsp?name=joe), I can do this, but when I try to retrieve it from the servlet I can only see the parameters passed in the AJAX Request, not the parameter in the URL...

Is there a reason this is happening? Should I go about this a different way?

Thank you!

Comment: move name=joe to AJAX request

Comment: I dont want this to be sent as a parameter every time the page is loaded though...

Comment: why every time - when needed or wanted

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like as if the Ajax request is actually a HTTP POST request. This way the GET query string in URL will indeed not be parsed. You need to parse it yourself in the `doPost()` method of the servlet. It's available by [`HttpServletRequest#getQueryString()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getQueryString%28%29).